# Need pseudo code for text compression/decompression

Tags: java

Specifications: You are to write a simple text compress and decompress algorithm called Compress, which uses the counts of repeated characters to compress and recoveries that compress text to the original text.  The data will be read in from a file not the keyboard.

Input: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAabc
Output: a19A1a1b1c1

In your program you must have these two methods below.  Then you call these two methods in your main method to compress and decompress your input text.

Public static String CompressStr(String input, Boolean debug_sw)

Public static String DecompressStr(String input, Boolean debug_sw)

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: How about: Read file; Replace "sequence of chars" with "count+char"; Write file.

Answer (score 2):

That's the Run-Length encoding algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding

```
  Loop: count = 0
        REPEAT
          get next symbol
          count = count + 1
        UNTIL (symbol unequal to next one)
                output symbol
        IF count > 1
          output count
        GOTO Loop
```

Some Python code:

```
# http://acm.zhihua-lai.com

def runlen(s):
    r = ""
    l = len(s)
    if l == 0:
        return ""
    if l == 1:
        return s + "1"
    last = s[0]
    cnt = 1
    i = 1
    while i < l:
        if s[i] == s[i - 1]: # check it is the same letter
            cnt += 1
        else:
            r = r + s[i - 1] + str(cnt) # if not, store the previous data
            cnt = 1
        i += 1
    r = r + s[i - 1] + str(cnt)
    return r

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print runlen("aaabbccccddddd")
    print runlen("a")
    print runlen("")
    print runlen("abcdefg")
    print runlen("eeeeeaaaff")
```

Answer (score -1):

Java has classes for this in the standard API: Zip/GZipInputStream and Zip/GZipOutputStream. If you need to compress data, use those instead of rolling your own. If you're doing this as a learning exercise, you're better off trying to read the algorithm for Zip.

Comment: Not my downvote, but this does not answer the question: "You are to write a simple text compress and decompress algorithm ... *which uses the counts of repeated characters*" i.e. RLE not LZW etc